# Strange issue with strcspn in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2012

I have this strange issue with `strcspn()` in Visual Studio 2012.

When I compile the following code as a 32 bit Win32 console application I get the expected result of 6.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  char delimiter_ = ',';
  std::string css_ = "ESCAPE,,0,0";

  printf( "%s\n", css_.c_str(  ) );
  printf( "%d\n", strcspn( css_.c_str(  ), &delimiter_ ) );

  size_t lengthOfField = strcspn( css_.c_str(  ), &delimiter_ );
  printf( "%d\n", lengthOfField );

  std::cin.get(  );

  return 0;
}
```

However, if I compile this same code for x64, I get the unexpected result of 4. Is there something I should no or is this a bug in VS2012?
This issue exists when using either `cstring` or `string.h` for the `strcspn()` method.

In a separate project, at one point the problem exists but instead of showing a result of 4 in x64, it shows for Win32 but shows 6 for x64. In a different file in this same project the issue is the same as above. It would appear to be some sort of UB but clearly the code given can reproduce this issue and as far as I know I haven't introduced any UB here.

EDIT: After some further testing, using `cout` instead of `printf` the values returned have also been 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

strcspn need pointers to null terminated strings as both params, you need to fix you code as following.

```
char delimiter_[] = ",";
printf( "%d\n", strcspn( css_.c_str(  ), delimiter_ ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `strcspn` is supposed to be a null terminated c-string.  You are just passing it the address of a single character.  It will treat that single character as the beginning of a c-string, scanning forward until it finds a null terminator.  But since it is not a c-string, and you don't have rights to any of the characters after the first, it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of [`strcspn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcspn) shall be C-style string not a single character.

```
size_t strcspn( const char *dest, const char *src );
```

Then use below

```
std::string delimiter_ = ",";

strcspn(css_.c_str(), delimiter.c_str());
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: +1 for begin right *and* linking the doc to `strcspn()`, which, though well explained, other answers seemingly missed.

Answer (score 0):

`css_.find(delimiter)` is much easier to write.